# Для чего тут используется функция count()?

Tags: php, массивы, count

```
if (isset($errors) && count($errors) > 0) {
      echo $message;
      foreach($errors as $error) {
        echo "$error<br />";
      }
```

Для чего тут используется функция `count()`, ведь если `isset()` выполнится, то понятно, что массив содержит больше одного элемента или нет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isset` проверяет на `NULL`, оно не проверяет на пустоту. Для проверки на пустоту существует [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Так что, тут `count` для проверки на то, есть ли в `$errors` элементы. Можно всё заменить на:

```
if (!empty($errors)) {
      echo $message;
      foreach($errors as $error) {
        echo "$error<br />";
      }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Проверка на существование и на пустоту - это две разные проверки.

Для того чтобы выполнить их одновременно, в РНР есть оператор empty()

```
if (!empty($errors)){
```